# Simulate a url/href with click() and location create a error

Tags: jquery, firefox, click, location

I dynamical create a list with some elements which should be clickable. It's not a simple text but a table row so I wanted to use the click() feature.

This is the way I do it:

```
function PrepareServerItem(item, server)
{
    item.attr("id", "srv" + server.id);
    if (server.status == 0) item.click(function() { window.location = "cndr://" + server.url; });
    return item;
}

function CreateServerItem(server)
{
    return PrepareServerItem(serverItem.clone(true), server);
}

[....]
$("#someid").before(CreateServerItem(server));
```

cdnr is a url protocol defined by a external program. This way works on chrome (still with a error -

> "GET cndr://JCMCFCMCCCMFJSRDBBF
>   undefined (undefined)"

but it opens the external program with the right parameter) but I got the following error within firefox:

> uncaught exception: [Exception...
>   "Failure" nsresult: "0x80004005
>   (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)" location: "JS
>   frame :: my internet address ::
>   anonymous :: line 186" data: no]

Could it be that changing the location removes the current document and so also some stuff which the script needs? How can I solve the problem?

Comment: have you tried using window.open to see if that gives any better results if you are worried about it being your use of .location?

Comment: window.open works without a error message but it opens a new tab.

Comment: does an <a> link work with the CDNR url protocol work on both browsers?

Comment: ah. I thought browsers these days didn't actually open the tab if they realised that it actually went to an exteranl app (or is a download or similar). If you need it to not open a new tab and you need it not to replace your current page then maybe hidden iframes might work for you (ie create a hidden iframe, load your url in it, browser recognises it as an external app and opens it, your page is not unloaded and you can get rid of the iframe (or leave it for the next click).

Comment: Niko, yes it works and Chris thank you for your hints I will try it with a iframe. PS: Can I somehow mark a comment as the solution to my problem here?

Comment: No, it has to be turned into an answer first.